# why isn't TestInitialize getting called automatically?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I'm `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;` but the method I marked as [TestInitialize] isn't getting called before the test. I've never used this particular testing framework before but in every other framework there is always a way of registering a Setup and TearDown method that will auto run before and after every single test. Is this not the case with the visual studio testing tools unit testing framework?

```
[TestClass]
public class RepoTest
{
    private const string TestConnectionString = @"Server=localhost\SQL2014EXPRESS64; Database=RepoTest; Trusted_Connection=True;";
    private const string MasterConnectionString = @"Server=localhost\SQL2014EXPRESS64; Database=master; Trusted_Connection=True;";

    [TestInitialize]
    private void Initialize()
    {
        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(MasterConnectionString))
        using(var command = new SqlCommand(Resources.Initialize, connection))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    private void Cleanup()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(MasterConnectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(Resources.Cleanup, connection))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateARepo()
    {
        var repo = new Repo(TestConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably needs to be public.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make `Initialize` and `Cleanup` public. You can also check, that at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx) all examples have public accessor.

In order to reproduce, make such test class:

```
[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("initialize");
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("cleanup");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test body");
    }
}
```

That test will produce the following results:

[image]

Making `Initialize` and `Cleanup` private, you'll see only `test body` being printed to the console:

[image]

Used Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework assembly as unit testing framework version **10.1.0.0** and ReSharper **8.2** as a test runner.